# Nginx - Redirect based on query string parameters

Tags: nginx

We have a bit of a complicated problem to solve in our nginx configuration. Currently we have a piece of software installed  in our document root. This software uses a single entry point (index.php) and query strings in order to show content. Example URLs are:

```
/index.php?forums/forum-name.1
/index.php?threads/thread-name.1
/index.php?users/user-name.1
```

Etc...

Now, we are moving this software into a subdirectory of `/f/` and installing a new piece of software into the document root. This software ALSO uses index.php (No query strings, though). So we need to come up with a set of rewrite rules to ONLY rewrite the URLs from the old software. At the same time, we are also going to be removing the index.php from the URLs. A set of example mappings is:

```
/index.php?forums/forum-name.1 --> /f/forums/forum-name.1
/index.php?threads/thread-name.1 --> /f/threads/thread-name.1
/index.php?users/user-name.1 --> /f/users/user-name.1
```

So basically, I need to redirect a certain subset of index.php requests (Only containing ?forums, ?threads, ?users, etc...), then remove the index.php part and send to the /f/ directory.

I have played with this all morning and just can't get it to work how I need it to.

Comment: You could use a `map` directive - see [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191594/nginx-rewrite-a-lot-2000-of-urls-with-parameters/49192527#49192527).

Comment: I don't think I can use map for this, as I don't have a static listing of original URLs, and even if I did, the numbers would be in the hundreds of thousands...I need some sort of regex matching.

Comment: Map supports regular expressions.

Comment: Right you are. That worked great! Thanks. Do you want to add an answer with this so that I can accept it or do you want me to self-answer it?

Answer (score 5):

To manage complex redirections, particularly when query strings are involved, the `map` directive can be used.

You cannot match the query string (anything from the `?` onwards) in `location` and `rewrite` expressions, as it is not part of the normalized URI, however, the `$request_uri` contains the original request complete with query string.

Matching the `$request_uri` may be problematic if the parameters are not sent in a consistent order, also URIs containing strange characters will be percent encoded.

The `map` directive can match strings and/or regular expressions. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.

For example:

```
map $request_uri $redirect {
    default                                               0;
    ~*^/index\.php\?(?<suffix>(forums|threads|users).*)$  /f/$suffix;
    ...
}

server {
    ...
    if ($redirect) {
        return 301 $redirect;
    }
    ...
}
```

Always use *named captures* in a `map` block regular expression. The mapped expression is evaluated at the `return` statement. As I understand it, every time `nginx` encounters a statement containing a *regular expression* (such as `rewrite`, some `location` blocks, and some `if` statements), the numeric captures are reset. Using *named captures* ensures that they remain in scope at the `return` statement.

See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

Comment: Thank you for the help, Richard. I have the code working on my end with regular (unnamed) captures. Why the warning on always using named captures?

Comment: I have expanded the answer.

Comment: Query string values are available in the variables `$args` for the complete string, `$arg_name` for a single argument by name and `$is_args` which will be a `?` if there is a query string and empty if not. You can evaluate these within location blocks and add them to return, rewite, proxy_pass etc directives

Comment: @miknik you should post your solution as an answer.

Comment: I didn't feel it was any better than your suggestion, particularly as the $arg_name variables are only populated if the query string uses key/value pairs separated by `=` which is not the case in the OPs setup. I just thought it was worth noting query string variables are captured by Nginx.