# Filtering the $query_string in Nginx

Tags: nginx

How would I best filter traffic based on the request URI? What I'd like to do is limit access to the script `some-script.php` when only a certain argument list is given. For instance, allow everyone to reach `user_info` with associated `user_id` value, but deny everyone access to `action=admin_login` unless their IP address is on the LAN.

I know `if` is evil and `allow all` won't work as shown below but I can't seem to find what I'm wanting to do.

```
location ~* /live/some-script\.php {

   // allow "?action=user_info&user_id=[0-9]{1,6}"
   if ($request_uri ~* "action=bwg_frontend_data" ) {
      allow all;
   }

  // deny everyone access to "?action=admin_login", but allow 192.168.100.0/24
  if ($request_uri ~* "?action=admin_login.*")
  {
      allow from 192.168.100.0/24;
  }

  return 403;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to match is not the $request_uri, but the $query_string.

$request_uri in your case is /live/some-script.php , while $args is everything after ? (easy way to explain it to simplify this). I will be leaving the links on where you can be helped on what you want, as I can't comment your post because I have not enough reputation.

For matching the querystring:

https://gist.github.com/psd/3884613

[Nginx - Redirect based on query string parameters](https://serverfault.com/questions/930145/nginx-redirect-based-on-query-string-parameters)

There is also another way with custom errors, but I kinda don't like it( you can use it if you want, it's a personal opinion):

[Can nginx location blocks match a URL query string?](https://serverfault.com/questions/811912/can-nginx-location-blocks-match-a-url-query-string/811981)

```
map $query_string $is_admin {
    ~ action=admin_login.* 1; # admin = 1
}
map $query_string $is_user {
    ~ action=bwg_frontend_data 1; #admin = 1
}
#default is empty, so it will not match the "if below".
```

Then inside your server code, you match $is_admin and $is_user with an if.

```
location ~* /live/some-script\.php {

   // allow "?action=user_info&user_id=[0-9]{1,6}"
   if ($is_user) {
      allow all;
   }

  // deny everyone access to "?action=admin_login", but allow 192.168.100.0/24
  if ($is_admin)
  {
      allow from 192.168.100.0/24;
      deny_all; #deny anyone but the allowed ones = https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/blocking-allowing-ip-addresses-in-nginx/
  }

  return 403;
}
```

I'm just giving you the theoretical way of doing it, as I can't see your whole config, just comment if it's right or if it's not, so I can edit it adapting it on what you want. I hope it's what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks, that's awesome. I had to table that project yesterda but when I get back to it I'll post results.

Comment: I would use `$arg_action` for the matching instead of `query_string`. Then nginx will extract the argument value and the `map` can be simpler.

Comment: I'm having trouble adding the `map{}` in my config.  Does this configuration item need to be added in a specific config section? The file in my post above is actually in an "include" file which gets pulled in from the `server` section in `sites-enabled/site.ssl`.

Comment: Think I got it working. Not sure if it's the right way to go, but added an `http.d/request_maps.conf` directory/file and included it in the nginx `http` section. This seems to pull it in the correct way. I want minimal edits in `nginx.conf` so ubuntu upgrades don't whack all my changes.

Comment: in the location directive, I can define a `return 410` in the `if` block,  but not `allow all`. Does this have something to do with the include location as well? tried moving the include into the `http` block but then it was upset with the `location` directive.

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon, everyone. In any case, you will need filtering not only fields, but also filtering forms, URL links, etc. I have not been looking for a similar solution for a long time, but for other purposes, and found an article on the Internet where the filtering function is described in detail. The truth is there is a php solution. Here https://cryptoxer.ru/forum/url-php-help / it says how to do it, I will not duplicate this superfluous. You can study the article in detail yourself and get something useful for yourself. There is a working code written there, take it and use it in your project.