# Nginx remove duplicate parameter in URL

Tags: nginx, rewrite, url

I have a site which has an issue causing an annoying URL issue. On the page numbers found on a page, if you follow one it will visit `?page=2`, this is fine.

If you then follow any subsequent links, rather than replacing the `?page=2`, it will append a new one. For example: `?page=2&page=3`. For various reasons, I need this to be `?page=3` and to remove the extroneous parameter from the beginning.

Sadly fixing this in code is not possible at this time and I wonder if anyone has ever done something similar through an NGINX rewrite.

Comment: please share your Nginx config. I don't believe it is coming from the webserver

Comment: This issue is not coming from the webserver, I am wondering if I can use the rewrite function on NGINX to patch it up (even badly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot fix this using the `rewrite` as it only operates on the part of the URI before the query string.

The query string is contained in the `$request_uri` and `$args` variables, which can be manipulated using regular expressions with `if` and/or `map` directives.

To process your specific case, you could use:

```
if ($request_uri ~ ^(.*)[?]page=2&page=(.*)$) { return 301 $1?page=$2; }
```

For an example using `map`, see this answer: [Nginx - Redirect based on query string parameters](https://serverfault.com/questions/930145/nginx-redirect-based-on-query-string-parameters/930187#930187)

Comment: That's exactly what I was hoping for, thank you!